# Adding margin top to rows in tableView

Tags: swift

How can I add margin top to rows in tableView? Now I have:

[image: Screenshot]

Can I add space between rows?

My code is:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    cell.imageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true

    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
    cell.textLabel?.text = postTitle[indexPath.row]

    cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius =  39
    cell.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true;

    return cell
}
```

I did try this line of code, but nothing:

```
cell.imageView.frame = CGRectOffset(cell.frame, 10, 10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code for spacing between cells:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10; // space b/w cells
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return postTitle.count // count of items
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = UIView()
    let imageName = "Divider.png"
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 1)
    header.addSubview(imageView)
    header.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    return header
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfeHL.png) is divider image for you.

Comment: it works! Thanks, but the lines between rows disappears. How can I return them?

Comment: you can use divider image for it and add it into header view.

Comment: http://imgur.com/Y8mXpRs || thank you for all! Can I remove the first top divider, add padding from top and bottom of the circular image and remove tableView row dividers?

Comment: you can post another question for it...: )

Comment: Can I add these lines under the cell??? Now comes line, later cell. But I want cell and later the line